# Exception while instantiating MockRunner- [NoSuchMethodError] [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking, okhttp

I have created a library for distribution the network requests amongst different clients. I am using `OkHttp3` in one of the clients. For testing my library, I am trying to mock the response using the [`okhttp3.mockwebserver`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver). The way I am trying to set up my mock web server is as follows:

```
val server = MockWebServer()
server.start()
val baseUrl = server.url("https://api.stage.zeta.in/zeta.in")

server.enqueue(MockResponse().setBody("{userID: 345923}"))
```

I am getting the following exception on line `val server = MockWebServer()`:

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableListOf([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;

    at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.<init>(MockWebServer.kt:176)
    at in.zeta.android.networkrouter.MyTestClass.setup(MyTestClass.kt:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:176)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:142)
```

Not sure where I am making a mistake. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue - did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version numbers of MockWebServer and OkHttp are the same.

Comment: getting same error even after making the same version for both.